# processing output of time command in a python script

Tags: python, time

I am trying to write a python script that benchmarks several pieces of code. The issue is when the script is run the output of the command id different from what I would get it I run it directly at bash prompt.

Here is the code for the python script

```
import subprocess
import re
import os
app = os.getcwd() + "/" + "myapp"
testPopen = subprocess.Popen(args=['/usr/bin/time',app],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False) 
testPopen.wait()
```

Here is the ouput of above code

```
    real        1.0
    user        0.8
    sys         0.0
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `timeit`?

Comment: well, for one this was a simple test not much accuracy needed for another I wasnt looking to time python rather a c++ program. but yeah that is one option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `time myapp` from the bash prompt, you are using [bash's `time` command](http://ss64.com/bash/time.html). (Type `help time` to see that bash understands it as a bash command.)

When you run the python script you are using `/usr/bin/time`, which is a [different program](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?time). (Type `man time` or `which time` to see that time is also a program. How confusing!)

To get the python script to use the bash time command:

```
import shlex
testPopen = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('bash -c "time {a}"'.format(a = app)),
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False) 
out,err = testPopen.communicate()
print(err)
```